# Subtracting arrays from arrays with sub-arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

In my Python programming course, we are discussing how to manipulate (add,subtract,etc.) arrays and sub-arrays. An example from class was if we had

```
ourArray = [['a','b','c'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j'],['k','l','m','n','o','p']...]
```

and `Array = ['a','e','i','k',...]`, would something like `ourArray-Array` be possible?

I tried

```
for w in ourArray:
    w[0] - Array[0]
```

In the end, what I would like is

```
[['a','b','c'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j'],['k','l','m','n','o','p']...] - ['a','e','i','k',...] = ['b','c'],['f','g','h'],['j'],['l','m','n','o','p']...].
```

Also, I am using Python 3 in Windows.

Comment: set difference sounds like what you want (but it doenst  preserve order...)

Answer (score 2):

How about this [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html), Pythonic, one liner:

```
>>> ourArray = [['a','b','c'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j'],['k','l','m','n','o','p']]
>>> Array = ['a','e','i','k']
>>> [[item for item in arr if item not in Array] for arr in ourArray]
[['b', 'c'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['j'], ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']]
```

For each array in `ourArray`, take only the items that are not in `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do the brute force method

```
>>> ourArray = [['a','b','c'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j'],['k','l','m','n','o','p']]
>>> Array = ['a','e','i','k']
>>> for i in ourArray:
...     for j in i:
...          if j in Array:
...                i.remove(j)
... 
>>> ourArray
[['b', 'c'], ['f', 'g', 'h'], ['j'], ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']]
```